# Android - Calling a fragment from an activity

Tags: android

[1]I need to call a fragment on a click from overflow menus . While I am on my Bankingactivity.java and when I call my MoneyTransferFragment.java it is easily accesible but when I am trying to call MoneyTransferFragment.java from any othe r activity it is getting crashed . I dont have a activity for MoneyTransferFragment.java and also cant make due to some data parsing issues .

In the BankingActivity.java I have called Fragment manager to replace the fragments .The given code snippet is from BankingActivity.java. When the same code I m trying to paste in any other activity it is getting crashed .I m pasting the code snippet from Bnkingactivity.java

```
case R.id.i3:
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        moneyTransferFragment = new MoneyTransferFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder,moneyTransferFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("money");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        break;

private void defaultSummaryScreen()
    {
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        accountSummaryFragment = new AccountSummaryFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder,accountSummaryFragment);
        // fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("summary");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

//statementactivity.java

```
public class StatementActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements FragmentConnector{

private MiniStatement miniStatement;
private DetailedStatement detailedStatement;
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
private MoneyTransferFragment moneyTransferFragment;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private AccountSummaryFragment accountSummaryFragment;

//PagerTitleStrip pagerTitle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_statements);
    miniStatement = new MiniStatement();
    detailedStatement = new DetailedStatement();

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

    ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>Statements </font>"));
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#787777")));
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.new_ic);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


}

/*public void handleClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.pager_title_strip:
        pagerTitle.setVisibility(0);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}*/

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if (position == 0){
            return miniStatement;
        }else if (position == 1){
            return detailedStatement;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        if (position == 0) {
            return "Mini Statement";
        }
        if (position == 1) {
            return "Detailed Statement";
        }

        return null;
    }
}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //  Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.i1:

        Intent intent = new Intent(StatementActivity.this,BankingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    case R.id.i2:
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(StatementActivity.this, StatementActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
        break;

    case R.id.i3:
        ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFCCFF")));
        actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000000'>Money Transfer </font>"));

        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        moneyTransferFragment = new MoneyTransferFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.pager,moneyTransferFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("money");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        break;

    case R.id.i4:
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(StatementActivity.this, ChequeRequestActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent3);
        break;  
    case R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

        break;
    case R.id.i5:
        Intent inten4 = new Intent(StatementActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(inten4);
        break;  
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

@Override
public void CallBackFromFragment(String fragmentName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

LogCat ..Cant Upload Image

05-09 02:20:36.590: W/dalvikvm(2212): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a4cba8)
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212): Process: com.example.mybankapp, PID: 2212
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003d (com.example.mybankapp:id/fragmentholder) for fragment MoneyTransferFragment{b2e6c8c0 #2 id=0x7f05003d}
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-09 02:20:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: a look from your logcat at the crash point will be helpful

Comment: Please Provide the Layout and Activity Code for Other Activities

Comment: Post your crash log also.